# How to create Twitter vertical count button?

Tags: twitter, widgets

I saw vertical button by Twitter in some pages and tutorials but I couldn't find out how to get the code for it. How can I make it look like the first widget on this image?

[image: Twitter Social widgets]

Comment: You need to add `data-count="vertical"` to the `<a>` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="https://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button" data-via="your_screen_name" data-lang="en" data-related="anywhereTheJavascriptAPI" data-count="vertical">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

source: [Tweet Button | Twitter Developers](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)